# Increasing the speed of a SSRS report

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a report in the C# version of SSRS that I'm trying to get to run quicker. The actually data retrieval time is acceptable. However in order for the report to match another one in terms of rounding, 3 data sets are used to match the rounding that the other reports have exactly. Which means I have to join them for each dataset. I'm still new to SSRS reports so I wanted to ask if my optimization plan made sense.

1. I'm switching the report to use a pivoted set of data instead of having it create that format using a tablix.
2. Change the report from using the lookup to having it use the data pivoted in SQL.
3. Change another part of the report so that it won't pass so much meta data for formatting. Which is also checked inside the report.

Comment: do all of this in a Stored procedure I think you will find that it will be much quicker

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I'm guessing it will be much faster if it doesn't need to be pivoted with a tablix, I know the lookup functions for the 3 data sets doesn't help at all.

Comment: you could do all of this using 1 stored procedure and passing in any or all of the 3 variables, using ISNULL check if it's sql server.. then from the report the values / variables will be passed into the stored procedure.. it's actually quite easy..

Comment: Pivoting in SSRS is relatively quick. Doing Lookups on datasets is not.